# Questions regarding schizophrenic prodromal progression

Tags: schizophrenia

I have been researching schizophrenia(sz) for a long while now, especially concerning the prodromal and ultra high risk(UHR) phases. Diagnostic criteria, symptom progression, remission rates, etc. But I haven't been able to find research of prodromal "symptom wave" patterns. In developed sz, psychosis and other symptoms exhibit a wave formation, waxing and waning. Is such a wave pattern present in some form as the disorder develops? If so, how long can a wave of 'downtime' versus more severe symptoms last?

I also am having trouble getting a full understanding of the diagnostic criteria for prodromal and UHR, though UHR doesn't seem to be well-defined anyway. The symptom lists vary slightly per paper, but in only one have I seen any mention of sensory processing issues developing in prodrome, and PTSD-like hypervigilance seems to not be mentioned much. Are these symptoms not as common in prodrome? There are other symptoms(eye contact avoidance, social ability degradation, dissociation etc.) that I have the same question about but I don't want to get too long.

I have other questions, but **mainly I am looking for any sz specialist or someone experienced with sz willing to help me iron out these details with their experience**. I'd like to message them if possible. This matter is of personal concern to me. I haven't added any sources or detail because this question is more opening up the possibility for a correspondence, and it would take a long time to explain everything. It would be strictly objective and not related to therapy of any sort. I hope this question is not inappropriate for this forum.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.   There are a fair few questions here which can demand an extensive answer on their own and it is better to stick to one per post here, as posts like this result in huge answer posts.  Can you split your questions up into separate posts along with references to research you have conducted?

Comment: I can do that, I am definitely aware that these are very heavy questions. I didn't make multiple posts because I was hoping more to happen across someone who would be able to work with me to at least give me research pointers. I am not sure how many people you have here that happen to specialize in schizophrenia. I will make more detailed and separate posts with references though if that would be better.

Comment: Looking at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28351597 the relevance of UHR for predicting psychosis seems somewhat doubtful. Frankly distinguishing prodrome from UHR is in itself a good question; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC161730/

Comment: And you main/bolded "question", asking for someone to engage private correspondence with you, isn't the goal of this site.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will start by asking to distinguish between UHR and prodromal.